# Remove sp_executesql while executing a stored procedure using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

When I execute a stored procedure using Entity Framework, it generates below syntax:

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC test @CityIds',N'@CityIds nvarchar(1)',@CityIds=N'1'
```

Our DBA has raised a concern with these sort of queries and wants to get rid of sp_executesql.

The query should read:

```
exec test @CityIds=1
```

What are different ways in entity framework to achieve this?

Comment: **WHAT** concern did the DBA utter? This is a **perfectly safe**, parametrized query - what's to complain about?? I am not aware of any way to tell EF to change this behavior.....

Comment: I agree with your point. But the DBA was expecting that sp_executesql would create that query as a dynamic query and that would not help in caching execution plan.

Is there any workaround where we can create it without dynamic query?

Comment: It is ***NOT*** a dynamic query! It's just a simple, **properly parametrized** standard T-SQL query that gets executed, with its parameter values. And **no**, as far as I know, there's nothing in EF to "switch" this behavior off - it's after all the **generally accepted Best Practice** to execute **parametrized queries** against SQL Server

Comment: makes sense, thanks for the explanation. was just wondering about the execution plan caching point. any inputs on that?

Comment: Well, since it's a **properly parametrized** query, it will behave very well in the plan cache and *can be reused* for subsequent requests - even if the parameter *values* change ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of sp_executesql in entity framework/ADO.net is intentional.It was observed that sometimes in the generated sql it appeared that EF was very decisive between directly executing the query and sometimes using sp_executesql.The sp_executesql comes into play when there is a client side parameterization helping in the re-use of one parameterized compiled plan. When there is no parameter specified then SQL Server tries to do an auto parameterization helping in reuse of query plan.

More information about Query [Parameterization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2007/01/11/4-0-query-parameterization/) here and [execution pattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bindeshv/2010/07/12/ef-query-execution-pattern-usage-of-sp_executesql-vs-direct-execution-of-sql-statement/)

Hope below thread will helps you about how to use EXEC instead of sp_executesql  with EF.

[SQL Server Recognise SP_EXECUTESQL as object rather than Procedure Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606978/sql-server-recognise-sp-executesql-as-object-rather-than-procedure-name)