# SQL Server Recognise SP_EXECUTESQL as object rather than Procedure Name

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using `DBContext.Database.SqlQuery<entity>` to execute stored procedure from my C# code repository.

It works fine but I want to know that why it is executing procedure like below:

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC GetCaseList @CaseStage',N'@CaseStage int',@CaseStage=9
```

rather than

```
EXEC GetCaseList @CaseStage = 9
```

And is there any way that my all procedures execute from c# like this
`EXEC GetCaseList @CaseStage = 9` rather than `exec sp_executesql N'EXEC GetCaseList @CaseStage',N'@CaseStage int',@CaseStage=9`?

How can I make SQL Server Profiler to treat procedure name as object rather than SP_EXECUTESQL ?

Note: I want to execute procedure from c# as `EXEC GetCaseList @CaseStage = 9` because I am saving trace data through **SQL Server Profiler** in table format. And in **ObjectName** column, it is showing sp_executesql as object rather than procedure name(GetCaseList) as object. **I can make changes only from c# code.**

Comment: Can you show how exactly do you call `SqlQuery` method for the above output, e.g. the `sql` string, `parameters` (the signature is `SqlQuery<TElement>(string sql, params object[] parameters)`)

Comment: @IvanStoev Sure. `return DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<CaseList>("EXEC GetCaseList @CaseStage", new SqlParameter("@CaseStage", paramList.CaseStageID)).ToList();`

Comment: @Dhwani, what happens if you remove `EXEC` from your C# code, like this: `return DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<CaseList>("GetCaseList", new SqlParameter("@CaseStage", paramList.CaseStageID)).ToList();` ?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, Removing doesn't make much difference. It still execute with `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that most of the EF performed database calls use [`DbCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) with [`CommadType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx) `Text`, so although SqlServer recognizes SP calls, it executes them as text via `sp_executesql`.

To get the desired behavior, the command should be setup this way:

```
DbCommand command = ...;
command.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
command.CommandType = CommadType.StoredProcedure;
```

Unfortunately EF does not provide a standard way of specifying the command type. The solution I'm suggesting is based on:

- Custom SP call SQL syntax using `CallPrefix StoredProcedureName` in order to not interfere with regular calls
- EF command [interception](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/database-command-interception.aspx) to remove the prefix and change the command type before executing the command.

Here is the implementation:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception;

public static class Sp
{
    public const string CallPrefix = "CallSP ";

    public static string Call(string name) { return CallPrefix + name; }

    public class CallInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
    {
        public static void Install()
        {
            DbInterception.Remove(Instance);
            DbInterception.Add(Instance);
        }

        public static readonly CallInterceptor Instance = new CallInterceptor();

        private CallInterceptor() { }

        static void Process(DbCommand command)
        {
            if (command.CommandType == CommandType.Text && command.CommandText.StartsWith(Sp.CallPrefix))
            {
                command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Substring(Sp.CallPrefix.Length);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            }
        }

        public override void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            Process(command);
            base.ReaderExecuting(command, interceptionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

All you need is to add the above class to your project, call `Sp.CallInterceptor.Install()` once, for instance inside your `DbContext` static constructor:

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    static YourDbContext()
    {
        Sp.CallInterceptor.Install();
    }
    // ...
}
```

and then change your SP calls like this (using your sample):

from:

```
return DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<CaseList>("EXEC GetCaseList @CaseStage", 
    new SqlParameter("@CaseStage", paramList.CaseStageID)).ToList();
```

to:

```
return DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<CaseList>(Sp.Call("GetCaseList"), 
    new SqlParameter("@CaseStage", paramList.CaseStageID)).ToList();
```

which will generate (for `paramList.CaseStageID == 9`):

```
EXEC GetCaseList @CaseStage = 9
```

Comment: That works perfectly with least changes in existing code.

Comment: Ivan, I have some queries regarding your implementation. Why have you created private constructor - `private CallInterceptor() { }`? Should I impalement IDisposable interface on `CallInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor` and dispose `Instance` object ?

Comment: @Dhwani It's just a standard Singleton pattern implementation - the private constructor ensures only one instance is created from the class itself. The class itself is stateless, hence does not need to be disposable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It helps me to understand it better.

Answer (score 2):

Use of sp_executesql in entity framework/ADO.net is intentional.It was observed that sometimes in the generated sql it appeared that EF was very decisive between directly executing the query and sometimes using sp_executesql.The sp_executesql comes into play when there is a client side parameterization helping in the re-use of one parameterized compiled plan. 
When there is no parameter specified then SQL Server tries to do an auto parameterization helping in reuse of query plan.

It appears that the decision to use sp_executesql or a direct sql batch is governed by ADO.Net’s SQLCommand object. It appears per the Tabular Data Stream (TDS) there’s only 2 ways to execute a SQL query – use RPC to execute SQL stored procedure and use SQL Batch for T-SQL. So when we have a parameterized query we tend to use RPC and call sp_executesql.More about query [execution pattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bindeshv/2010/07/12/ef-query-execution-pattern-usage-of-sp_executesql-vs-direct-execution-of-sql-statement/).

More information about Query Parameterization [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2007/01/11/4-0-query-parameterization/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons as below:

**The Main reason(1):** The TSQL string is built only one time, after that every time same query is called with sp_executesql, SQL Server retrieves the query plan from cache and reuses it.

**(2):** sp_executesql allows for statements to be parameterized so it is more secure than EXEC in terms of SQL injection.

example for comparison please review below link:
[comparision of EXEC and EXEC sp_executesql](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/exec-and-sp_executesql-how-are-they-different/)

Comment: Yes that is true, but my point is SQL Server Profiler treats SP_EXECUTESQL as object, not the procedure name(GetCaseList) as object. How can I make SQL Server Profiler to treat procedure name as object rather than SP_EXECUTESQL ?

Comment: It is the default behavior of profile to trace like that but if you want to do filter by stored procedure of application then see this link:http://www.connectsql.com/2011/10/sql-server-using-sql-profiler-to.html

Comment: Yes we can do it like that. But I am getting trace data into table from our client DBA for specific duration. So, in that trace I'll have all procedures, select statement and other things of multiple database. So, I won't be getting exact count for each and every call of each procedure.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because the EF need to dynamic to generate the SQL command, so it's need to use `exec sp_executesql` for dynamic to execute the sql.

Comment: But I am just executing procedure not a query statement.